# Which Root CA certs required for Apple's 3/29/21 HTTP/2 cert change?

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications, ca

I've dug around and found several related questions mostly about Azure or Firebase, however, there are some users (myself being one of them) that directly send HTTP/2 push notification data to Apple.

Do we need all three Root CA's installed OR do we only need `AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020`?

On 2/10/21, we got the following email:

> On March 29, 2021, token and certificate-based HTTP/2 connections to
> the Apple Push Notification service must incorporate the new root
> certificate ([AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117cL)) which replaces the old
> GeoTrust Global CA root certificate. To ensure a seamless transition
> and to avoid push notification delivery failures, verify that both the
> old and new root certificates for the HTTP/2 interface are included in
> the Trust Store of each of your notification servers before March 29.
>
> Note that Apple Push Notification service SSL provider certificates
> issued to you by Apple do not need be to updated at this time.
>
> Learn more about connecting to APNs.
>
> If you have any questions, contact us.
>
> Best regards,  Apple Developer Relations

On the page linked above ([also here](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117cL)) there are three certificates listed for download:
[image: Root CA Certs available for download]

The Comodo RSA and USERTrust RSA certificates both have certification path dependencies on AAA Certificate Services:
[image]

Do we need all three Root CA's installed OR do we only need `AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mail you received the link is named (AAACertificateServices 5/12/2020), so this is the only certificate you need.

You can look also in the another link in the mail: [Learn more about connecting to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/). There is more info under **Establish a Trusted Connection to APNs** section.

**Edit:**

See also [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673837) at Developer Forums.